# upload file to a server swift

Tags: file, http, swift, upload

I just want to ask you how to simply upload a .csv file to a server .php file. In all other languages is straightforward, here I'm having a lot of troubles, I don't want to do complex things, only upload and see the server response.
Thanks.

Here's my code, I used this library https://github.com/daltoniam/SwiftHTTP

```
let fileUrl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath("/Users/mypath")
var request = HTTPTask()
request.POST("http://server.com/upload.php", parameters:  ["file": HTTPUpload(fileUrl: fileUrl)], success: {(response: HTTPResponse) -> Void in

    },failure: {(error: NSError, response: HTTPResponse?) -> Void in

    })
```

Comment: What troubles are you having? Show us your code and explain your problem.

Comment: probably the file: parameter is causing an erratic response from the server

Comment: Show us the server's error response including headers (and read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)